# Disallow an user to go up in the tree with pure-ftpd

Tags: busybox, ftp, home-directory

I added an user to pure-ftpd with `adduser -h /blah user`, using busybox.

Unfortunately, he is able to go up in the tree and see the root folder.

How can I disallow this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the file /etc/pure-ftpd/conf/ChrootEveryone

Enter the following in this file :

```
yes
```

Restart pure-ftpd

Answer (score 1):

You can start pure-ftpd with the -A options to chroot all users within their home directories. See [the FAQ](http://download.pureftpd.org/pub/pure-ftpd/doc/FAQ).